# Google login authentication feature not working (Google firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using google firebase to get google authentication system on my website, but whenever I click the button which has an onClick function that calls my google authentication component, it doesn't work.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCdHT-AYHXjF7wOrfAchX4PIm3cSj5tn14',
  authDomain: 'crwn-db.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://crwn-db.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'crwn-db',
  storageBucket: 'crwn-db.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '850995411664',
  appId: '1:850995411664:web:7ddc01d597846f65'
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

The code of where I am using the component is also given below..

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FormInput from "../form-input/form-input.component";
import CustomButton from "../custom-button/custom-button.component";
import "./sign-in.styles.scss";
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../firebase/firebase.utils";
class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "example@domain.com",
      password: "password"
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ email: "", password: "" });
    console.log("handle submit logs", this.state.email, this.state.password);
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    console.log("handleChange logs", this.state.email, this.state.password);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sign-in">
        <h2>I already have an account</h2>
        <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            name="email"
            type="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            // required
            label="email"
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <FormInput
            type="password"
            name="password"
            // required
            label="Password"
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.password}
          />
          <CustomButton type="submit">Log in</CustomButton>
          <CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
            {" "}
            Sign In with Google{" "}
          </CustomButton>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SignIn;
```

Btw this CustomButton is another react component which just acts like a normal button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to go detail,

First, you need to enable Sign-in method for google on Firebase console.
[image: firebase signin method enabling]

And apparently, you better move provider into your component which you are calling google auth.

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
```

and then pass provider as params to this function

```
export const signInWithGoogle = (provider) => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

This way, you will be able to get a proper provider and run it

My another tip for your code is to keep initialization with firebase in firebase util, and utilize that always when you need that

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't work. Earlier, what was happening is whenever I was trying to click the "Sign in with google" button, it used to open another window, like it should, then it used to close down automatically without asking user to log in with their google account. But now when I click my button, it doesn't even open that new window.

Comment: Should I add my github repository link, so that its easier for you to see my code?

Comment: That might be helpful, @MayBeNextT1me

Comment: But just wondering you might need to enable Sign-in method for Google. seems you didn't do that.
https://prnt.sc/uj8fsh

Comment: Yeah.. I noticed that I didn't enable sign-in method from Google's firebase website. :)

Comment: @MayBeNextT1me If this answer works for you, would you please accept, so I can edit this answer properly